# How to embed a Twitch Stream inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, streaming, embed, twitch

I am a novice programmer and I'm trying to create a program that has links to many popular 'streamers' on Twitch.tv. (For those who don't know: Twitch.tv is a streaming website for people who stream games). When a user clicks on a link (JButton) to their favourite streamer, I want to open the Twitch Video inside my program UI (A JFrame). How can I achieve this?

All I know is that it's possible with YouTube videos if you render them as HTML5, but Twitch doesn't seem to have this feature and should require Adobe Flash... I also tried searching online but to no avail...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of these two libraries:

http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html

or

http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/